# How long after new LTS release for certifications to come out?

Tags: 16.04, lts, hardware-certification, certification

On the Ubuntu certification website (http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/) laptops are only certified through 14.04; it doesn't look like any laptops have been certified with 16.04. Does anyone know when those certifications will be out? Looking to buy a new laptop to run Ubuntu and I'd like it to be certified.

Comment: Interestingly the server information for 16.04 is in place: http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/server/ . I have emailed the owners of the page for clarification, interesting to see if the response is prompt :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sent an email to the owners of the pages to do with certification of computer hardware and have just received a reply which I quote below (I have munged the email addresses to avoid spam):

```
Date: Wed, 29 Jun 2016 12:33:18 +0000
From: Anthony Dillon <anthonyxxxxn@canonical.com>
To: andrew <andrew.xxxxxxx@xxxx.com>
Subject: Re: Certified Hardware for 16.04

Hi Andrew,

We are starting to enable and certify systems with 16.04 images.

We have now 2 systems there and more will start appearing in the
following months.

All the best,
Ant.

On Sun, 19 Jun 2016 at 04:07 andrew <andrew.xxxx@xxxx.com> wrote:

    Hi,

    Concerning this page:

    http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/

    I note that for Desktop Hardware there are no entries for the latest
    release Xenial Xerus 16.04. Entries are in place for server hardware
    though.

    When will these entries be in place?

    Thanks,

    Andrew

    --
    You think that's air you're breathing now?
```

And I see that there are now 3 Dell Desktop systems [in place there](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/models/?release=16.04%20LTS&category=Desktop&category=Laptop) and hopefully as promised there will be more soon, including the laptops that you are after...